# 'I was using', 'I have used', 'I have been using', 'I had used' - what is the difference amongst these?

Tags: grammar, tenses

First, is my question right? Does *amongst* fit here?

Please differentiate the above phrases.

Comment: I would go with "difference between". There is not a single occurrence of "difference amongst" in the [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/), and while Google does return [25,700 hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22difference+amongst%22) for "difference amongst", it returns [74,100,000 hits](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22difference+between%22) for "difference between".

Comment: Are 'difference' and 'amongst' based on the count?? This questions generates more child questions. :-(

Comment: Are we are ELU? Sure? There's also the [ell.se]

Comment: @RegDwigнt Both "difference amongst" as well as "difference between" are used, in different situations. Not to compare on Google Search/ nGrams out of context.

Comment: ... But 'the difference between a, b and c' is standard.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> I have used cocaine.

I took cocaine at least once sometime in the past.

> I was using cocaine.

In the past, I was a habitual user of cocaine. EDIT: As the comment says, this can also mean a process in the past, e.g. "I was using cocaine when the accident happened" can mean "I was not looking at the road since I was snorting cocaine."

> I have been using cocaine.

Starting some time in the past, and including today, I use cocaine.

> I had used cocaine.

With my reference point at a time in the past, by that point, cocaine was already taken by me. Better example:

> By the time I met my girlfriend, I had used cocaine.

So when meeting the girlfriend, you took cocaine by then already.

BONUS: You missed one:

> I had been using cocaine.

Meaning, with a reference point in the past, starting a time before then up to the reference point, I was habitually using cocaine up to and including that point.

Why not put in some other wonky tenses?

> I will have used cocaine.
>
> I will have been using cocaine.

[Here](http://www.verbix.com/webverbix/English/use.html) is a link conjugating it in all its tenseful glory.

Comment: "I was using cocaine" may not indicate habitual use, but instead may refer to one's state at a particular time: "When I got into the accident, I was using cocaine."

Comment: nice coke reference :)

Comment: @Claudiu Is your lastname EyeOpener?? :-D Thanks for the great examples. I think the link would satisfy many of the questions. Thanks a lot.

Comment: "I used to use cocaine" -- a previous habit which has ceased.

Comment: @khedron: that's not a different tense, though, that's using a different construction ("I used to ...") .

Comment: @Claudiu: hmm, does that matter?  I mean that seriously, I can't tell.  I was originally going to phrase it as "I once used...", just to parallel your "I had used" but give it a different intent.  And then I figured that saying "used to use" was funnier.

Comment: @khedron: depends on what the question was. strictly speaking, anything not addressing those 4 phrases is off-topic. i expanded it to be any tense of 'to use', where 'have' and 'will' are used as auxiliary verbs. so "used to use" is off-topic of the 'tenses' answers. but it's on-topic for a more general time-passing-type-thing where the main verb is 'to use' and 'used' is an auxiliary verb(is it?) in this case

Comment: You should stop using cocaine...